# Spring mvc - REST webservice - one api is callable, another reports "No mapping found for HTTP request with URI"

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, tomcat

I've a Spring MVC REST service. It's annotation based and I don't have an XML config file.

The controller class is like following:

```
@RestController
public class CustomerInfoController
{
  ...
  @RequestMapping("/greet")
  public String helloGreeting()
  {
        return "Welcome to REST Test :-)";
  }

  @RequestMapping("/getCusomterInfo")
  public String getCustomerInfo(@RequestParam int vendorId, @RequestParam int customerId, @RequestParam boolean isDetail)
  {
   ....
   return "<result>";
   ...
  }
  ...
}
```

The webapp is deployed in Tomcat 8.5.11.

When the webapp war is deployed, I've confirmed the following 2 log lines on Tomcat console output:

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/getCusomterInfo]}" onto public java.lang.String com.vir.app.controller.CustomerInfoController.getCustomerInfo(int,int,boolean)

org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/greet]}" onto public java.lang.String com.vir.app.controller.CustomerInfoController.helloGreeting()
```

Which means the mapping was discovered and done during deployment.

I'm using Firefox RESTClient for testing.

The problem is that I get correct result for the dummy service greet(), but for the getCusomterInfo I get error as following:

*`org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound.noHandlerFound No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/virindia/getCustomerInfo] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'`*

The RESTClient displays 404 error resource not found.

Could anyone help me in figuring out the problem? Please remember, it's not a config file based configuration, only annotation based.

Comment: Do you recognize misspelling? RequestMapping("/getCusomterInfo")

Comment: :-) Please post it as answer so that I could mark it as such :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you recognize misspelling?

`RequestMapping("/getCusomterInfo")`

Answer (score 1):

There was simple typo.
You misspelled Customer.

```
Instead of 
@RequestMapping("/getCusomterInfo")

Change it to 
@RequestMapping("/getCustomerInfo")
```

It took me more than 2 minutes to find that typo.

Answer (score 0):

You has not controller for '/virindia/getCustomerInfo'.
Also you declare parameters: vendorId, customerId, isDetail

Try

```
/getCustomerInfo?vendorId=0&customerId=0&isDetails=true
```

or use Optional class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the annotation @ResponseBody to say to your controller you are going to translate to JSON format

```
@RequestMapping("/getCusomterInfo")
@ResponseBody
 public Customer getCustomerInfo(@RequestParam int vendorId, @RequestParam int customerId, @RequestParam boolean isDetail)
 {
      //here you should retrieve your customer entity
      return customer;
 }
```